# drive.comments.list for the MIME type "application/vnd.google-apps.form" returns 404 Not Found

Tags: google-drive-api

When I create a newly `application/vnd.google-apps.form` file and tries to retrieve it's comments with `drive.comments.list`, I receive a `404 Not Found` response instead of an empty list response.

Is it a bug? If so, when will it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot comment on forms. It is working as intended.

Comment: If so, why not return an empty list of comments?